# Как обновлять проект с репозитория?

Tags: git, android-studio, контроль-версий

Кто-то может расстолковать какая разница:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Merge
- Rebase
- Branch Default

И

- Using Stash
- Using Shelve

Что в каких случаях используется?

Comment: Вот что об этом говорит [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/update-project-dialog-git.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для начала git stash или git shelve. Когда Вы подтягиваете новые изменения, в Вашем рабочем каталоге могут быть измененные (незакоммиченные) файлы. Естественно, что эти файлы при слиянии изменений могут потерятся. Поэтому гит предлагает их "спрятать в карман". Это называется git stash. После того, как новый код будет получен с удаленного репозитория, изменения с stash можно  накатить назад (естественн, при этом возможно нужно будет решить конфликты). В "кармане" можно хранить сколько угодно изменений (логично - ограничены своим диском) и карман не передается на сервер. Детальнее о [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) на русском.

[git shelve](https://github.com/siebertm/git-shelve) - это древний проект (2008 года), который не поддерживается на данный момент. Как и git shash, умеет прятатть изменения, только в отдельные ветки. Зачем оно в студии - не ведомо.

Теперь о первой колонке. При накатывании чужих коммитов может произойти две ситуации - в ветке есть Ваши коммиты и чужие и когда есть только с одной стороны. Понятно, что когда есть только коммиты одной стороны, то принять изменения очень просто - их нужно просто "скопировать себе" и поправить указатели на ветки.

В том случае, если есть и свои коммиты и чужие, нужно их "сложить вместе". Для этого есть две технологии - merge и rebase. При merge происходит слияние файлов. Там, где файлы одинаковые, проблем нет, там где файлы разные, гит пытается сложить вместе. Иногда у него это не выходит и он просит пользователя "разрешить конфликт" - так как только программист знает, что он хочет.

Но есть второй способ - это rebase. Некоторые люди любят этот способ, а некоторые под страхом разрушить репозиторий боятся его использовать. Работает он очень просто. Сравниваются две ветки и ищется общий предок-коммит. Дальше, с локальной ветки откатываются все коммиты до общего коммита. Естественно, что теперь добавить коммиты с удаленного репозитория просто. После этого локальные коммиты "накатываются поверху". Если в процессе накатки возникают конфликты, их нужно решать.

А вот что такое Branch default - я не знаю, возможно, студия запоминает последний выбор и применяет его.

Comment: Вот нашел. Но мне это мало о чем говорит `Branch Default: choose this option to have the default command for the branch applied. The default command is specified in the branch.<name> section of the .git/config configuration file.`

Comment: Оно говорит, что в конфиге (.git/config) может быть сохранено желаемое поведение - rebase или merge.

Comment: Любопытно, что нет варианта c `--ff-only`, который мне кажется наиболее рациональным. Если `master` на сервере разошелся с моим локальным, ситуация может быть сколь угодно плохой, вплоть до деструктивного `push -f`. Меньше всего в этой ситуации нужен тихий мерж без предупреждений.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы добавил что Shelve это чисто фича IDEA https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html, кое в чём погибче, но git тоже на месте не стоит. 
Тут похожий вопрос был https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008139/git-shelve-vs-stash

Comment: Посмотрел на это shelve changes. При использовании открывается окно как будто создания коммита, но в результате появляется `.idea/shelf/<message>`, а внутри копия документа с `-` у убранных строк и `+` у добавленных. Какой-то формат патча, по всей видимости.