# Подтянуть изменения из master в свою ветку

Tags: git

У меня есть ветка и в неё необходимо подтянуть изменения которые произошли в мастере. Подскажите как как это сделать не потеряв изменения в своей ветке

Comment: Сделайте комит изменений в своей ветке, после этого выполните `git merge master` (находясь в своей ветке)

Comment: а можно сделать `git stash`, потом подмержить себе изменений и достать назад свои изменения - `git stash pop`, пофиксив конфликты

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Более "чистый" способ `git pull --rebase origin master`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обновлять проект с репозитория?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518059/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f)